# MS CRM Dynamics - browse to dynamics portal (from my application) without Login dialog?

Tags: authentication, microsoft-dynamics

From my C# application, I would like to open my dynamics portal within a browser.
I would like to do this with no need of the user to prompt his credentials in the Login dialog.
is it possible?

In salesforce.com for example it is possible. you can add a session info to your salesforce.com portal URL, in that way you can browse with that URL with no need to authenticate.

is that also possible in Dynamics CRM?

please help...

hagai